# Refresh value of IMPORTXML

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've been searching and cannot find a simple solution to update some cells in my Google Sheet.

Basically I have:

```
B3: https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/
C3: =IMPORTXML(B3,"//span[@class='text-large']")
B4: https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/litecoin/
C4: =IMPORTXML(B4,"//span[@class='text-large']")
...
```

I simply want cell C3, C4, C5 ... to be updated every minute (or even add a refresh button to the page to manually call a script to update).

I have 6 rows in the spreadsheet, but all essentially are the same. This number of rows could be 2 or up to 20 .. so flexibility is desired.

How can I make these cell formulas update every minute?

Comment: Are you looking a solution using [tag:google-apps-script]? Have you search/researched about how to do this? If so, what did you find? Reference: [ask].